# Reading dynamic file name in cypress test spec

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cypress

How can I parameterise a file name in a Cypress spec and load that file? I'm injecting other parameters via environment variables which works fine, but whatever is provided to `require(...)` does not get found as file (although the error message specifies the file name in the exact same way as if it was hardcoded).

```
describe('run test', () => {
  const data = require('../fixtures/my.json');
  it('foo', () {
   ...
  });
```

So in other words the above snipped behaves differently to:

```
describe('run test', () => {
  const file = Cypress.env('file');
  const data = require('../fixtures/' + file);
  data.forEach((entry) => {
    it(`foo testing ${entry}`, () {
     ... run a test based on `entry`
    });
  });
```

when calling cypress from the command line via `$(npm bin)/cypress run ... --env file=my.json`. In the example where the `file` parameter is provided, a file not found error message is shown (with the exact file path as for the hardcoded file name example). I believe this is because the `require()` doesn't get resolved at runtime (but before and thus cannot accept dynamic arguments), but I am not 100% certain and would also consider an alternative for reading the file.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't use `cy.fixture(\`/folder/${file}\`).then()`?

Comment: Because it doesn't seem to be possible: "Cannot call `cy.fixture()` outside a running test."

Comment: The result of `file` is required to create `it(...)` blocks.

Comment: I've updated the description to make this dependency clearer.

Comment:  I personally use `cy.fixture()` in `before()` in a `describe()` block. I'll try to solve this later

Comment: I'd be curious to see your solution. When `cy.fixture` is executed in `before()` the data won't be available to create the test case outside of `before`...

Comment: Sorry - you were totally right. Interesting problem. The only thing that's still in my head are [Typescript's dynamix import expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#dynamic-import-expressions). Is that something you could work with?

Comment: But those are not dynamic (i.e. evaluated at runtime). The `import()` is usually transpiled before execution (by webpack or similar). You won't be able to use a variable name there.

Comment: I've found this example recipe and it seems that what you want is not possible?!
[fundamentals__dynamic-tests](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/fundamentals__dynamic-tests)
Would love to hear when you find a solution

Comment: I kind of managed to implement the file loader by following your link. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Read-a-file-that-might-not-exist. `readFileMaybe` is called in `before()` and stores the content of the external file in a variable which then gets accessed in the test case (I used identifiers which come from outside via the env variable to construct the test cases and these identifiers reference the values in the loaded file). Quite indirect method to load data dynamically, but so far it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basic structure of the dynamic test case creation spec. It is populated by a combination of environment variables and a file. The elements in the environment variable `ids` specify the key for the individual test cases' parameters which are provided in a separate file (also specified via an environment variable)). The `ids` are serialised and delimited through an outside script.

Call this script via:

```sh
$(npm bin)/cypress run --config-file cypress.json --headless --env ids=foo@bar@blah,paramsFile=myParamfile.json
```

#### features/test_xyz.js

```js
let paramsFile = Cypress.env('paramsFile');
let ids = Cypress.env('ids');


describe('My test', () => {
  let params;

  before(() => {
    cy.task('readFileMaybe', paramsFile).then(fileContent => {
      if (fileContent === null) {
        throw new Error(`Could not find file ${paramsFile}.`);
      }
      // params = {id1: testcaseParam2, id2: testcaseParam2, ...}
      // `testcaseParamX` are objects or arrays and can therefore not be passed
      // easily into the test case via environment variables.
      params = JSON.parse(fileContent);
    });
  });

  // `ids` is a string -> needs to be split
  // e.g. `ids.split(delim).forEach(...)` to actually run.
  ids.forEach(id => {
    // Create test case.
    it(`test case for ${id}`, () => {
      let param = params[id];

      // run assertions here...
    });
  });
});
```

#### `plugins/index.js` ([reference](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Event))

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    // Needs to be done through a task, as we can't access `fs` in test case
    // (this task runs in Node which allows use of external libraries).
    readFileMaybe(filename) {
      // console.log('Loading ', filename);
      if (fs.existsSync(filename)) {
        return fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
      }
      // console.log('Could not find ', filename);
      return null;
    }
  });
};
```

This was extremely painful to get working. However, the ability to run commands outside of the Cypress context directly in Node is very powerful and can be used for similar problems, too. I hope others find this useful.

Answer (score -3):

In your spec file use the env variable in require statement like this.
This works with version 8.3 and above

```
$(npm bin)/cypress run ... --env file=my.json

const data = require(`../fixtures/${Cypress.env(file)}`);

describe('run test', () => {
 
  it('foo', () {
   ...
  });

(or)

$(npm bin)/cypress run ... --env file=my

const data = require(`../fixtures/${Cypress.env(file)}.json`);

describe('run test', () => {
 
  it('foo', () {
   ...
  });
```

Comment: that's what I did. see my answer: `paramsFile=myParamfile.json`

Comment: @orange try adding it before the describe block